# Graphic manipulation - Psychrometric chart

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts, code, engineering

I'm working on a psychrometric chart on Mathematica. The code is as follows:

```
(*psat is saturation pressure calculated by Hyland Wexler correlation*)
psat[T_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[(c8/(T + 273.15)) + 
   c9 + (c10*(T + 
       273.15)) + (c11*((T + 273.15)^2)) + (c12*((T + 
         273.15)^3)) + (c13*Log[T + 273.15])]
c8 = -5800.2206;
c9 = 1.3914993;
c10 = -0.04860239;
c11 = 0.41764768*10^-4;
c12 = -0.14452093*10^-7;
c13 = 6.5459673;
patm = 101325;(*Pa*)(*atm pressure*)
rn = 0.622;(*kg/kg*);(*molar ratio*)
cp = 1.004;(*KJ/kg K*);(*air specific heat*)
hvref = 2501;(*KJ/kg*);(*vapour enthalpy*)
cpda = 1.006;(*KJ/kg K*);(*specific heat dry air*)
cpwv = 1.84;(*KJ/kg K*);(*specific heat water vapour*)

(*Y is humidity ratio as function of relative humidity and temperature*)
Y[phi_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := (rn*phi*psat[T])/(patm - psat[T])

phiPlot = Table[Plot[Y[phi, T], {T, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Blue}], {phi,0.1, 1, 0.1}];

phiSatPlot = Plot[Y[1, T], {T, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}];

Tref = 0;

(*YB is humidity ratio as function of enthalpy and temperature*)
YB[h_?NumericQ,T_?NumericQ] := (h - (cpda*(T + 273.15 - (Tref + 273.15))))/((cpwv*(T + 273.15 - (Tref + 273.15))) + hvref)

h1Plot = Table[Plot[YB[h, T], {T, 0, 55}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red},PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}], {h, 0, 200, 5}];

Show[h1Plot, phiSatPlot, phiPlot, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[0, 0.050, 0.002]}, {Range[0, 50, 10], 
    None}}]
```

So the following graphic shows humidity ratio (Y axis), dry bulb temperature (x axis), relative humidity (blue lines) and enthaply

[image: psychrometric chart]

The issue is that I can't erase the enthalpy (red) lines above the saturation line (green curve). Does anybody knows how I could do that?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you please include definition for  `psat`?

Comment: `phiSatPlot = Plot[Y[1, T], ...` What is `Y`? Please add all this info to your post and delete your comments. Make sure you copy from this web page to a new notebook on a fresh kernel. If you can't see the plot, we can't see it either.

Comment: Thank you @Syed! I did the alterations and tried the code in a new notebook to check the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c8 = -5800.2206;
c9 = 1.3914993;
c10 = -0.04860239;
c11 = 0.41764768*10^-4;
c12 = -0.14452093*10^-7;
c13 = 6.5459673;
patm = 101325;
Tref = 0;

(*Pa*)(*atm pressure*)rn = 0.622;(*kg/kg*);(*molar ratio*)cp \
    = 1.004;(*KJ/kg K*);(*air specific heat*)hvref = \
    2501;(*KJ/kg*);(*vapour enthalpy*)cpda = 1.006;(*KJ/kg K*);(*specific \
    heat dry air*)cpwv = 1.84;(*KJ/kg K*);(*specific heat water \
    vapour*)(*Y is humidity ratio as function of relative humidity and \
    temperature*)

    Y[phi_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := (rn*phi*psat[T])/(patm - psat[T])
    
    (*psat is saturation pressure calculated by Hyland Wexler correlation*)


psat[T_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[(c8/(T + 273.15)) + 
   c9 + (c10*(T + 
       273.15)) + (c11*((T + 273.15)^2)) + (c12*((T + 
         273.15)^3)) + (c13*Log[T + 273.15])]

(*YB is humidity ratio as function of enthalpy and temperature*)
YB[h_?NumericQ, 
  T_?NumericQ] := (h - (cpda*(T + 
        273.15 - (Tref + 273.15))))/((cpwv*(T + 
        273.15 - (Tref + 273.15))) + hvref)

h1Plot = ListLinePlot[
   Table[YB[h, T], {h, 0, 200, 5}, {T, 0, 55}]
   , PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Red}}
   ];

phiPlot = 
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Y[phi, T], {phi, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}], {T, 0, 50}
   , PlotStyle -> Blue
   , PlotRange -> {0, 0.05}
   , PlotRangePadding -> None
   , Frame -> True
   , FrameTicks -> {
     {None, Range[0, 0.050, 0.002]}
     , {Range[0, 50, 10], None}
     }
   , ImageSize -> 500
   ];

phiSatPlot = Plot[Y[1, T]
   , {T, 0, 50}
   , PlotStyle -> {Thick, Darker@Green}
   , PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}
   , FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, HatchFilling[-10 Degree, 0.2, 7]]
   , Filling -> {1 -> {Top, Directive[Opacity[1], White]}}
   
   ];

Show[phiPlot, h1Plot, phiSatPlot]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Syed! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Add a white domain `erasePlot` to the plot.

```
erasePlot = 
  Plot[Y[1, T], {T, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}, Filling -> Top, 
   FillingStyle -> White];
Show[h1Plot, phiSatPlot, phiPlot, erasePlot, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[0, 0.050, 0.002]}, {Range[0, 50, 10], 
    None}}]
```

[image]

```
(*psat is saturation pressure calculated by Hyland Wexler correlation*)
psat[T_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[(c8/(T + 273.15)) + 
   c9 + (c10*(T + 
       273.15)) + (c11*((T + 273.15)^2)) + (c12*((T + 
         273.15)^3)) + (c13*Log[T + 273.15])]
c8 = -5800.2206;
c9 = 1.3914993;
c10 = -0.04860239;
c11 = 0.41764768*10^-4;
c12 = -0.14452093*10^-7;
c13 = 6.5459673;
patm = 101325;(*Pa*)(*atm pressure*)
rn = 0.622;(*kg/kg*);(*molar ratio*)
cp = 1.004;(*KJ/kg K*);(*air specific heat*)
hvref = 2501;(*KJ/kg*);(*vapour enthalpy*)
cpda = 1.006;(*KJ/kg K*);(*specific heat dry air*)
cpwv = 1.84;(*KJ/kg K*);(*specific heat water vapour*)

(*Y is humidity ratio as function of relative humidity and \
temperature*)
Y[phi_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := (rn*phi*psat[T])/(patm - psat[T])

phiPlot = 
  Table[Plot[Y[phi, T], {T, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Blue}], {phi, 
    0.1, 1, 0.1}];

phiSatPlot = 
  Plot[Y[1, T], {T, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}];

Tref = 0;

(*YB is humidity ratio as function of enthalpy and temperature*)
YB[h_?NumericQ, 
  T_?NumericQ] := (h - (cpda*(T + 
        273.15 - (Tref + 273.15))))/((cpwv*(T + 
        273.15 - (Tref + 273.15))) + hvref)

h1Plot = 
  Table[Plot[YB[h, T], {T, 0, 55}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}], {h, 0, 200, 5}];

erasePlot = 
  Plot[Y[1, T], {T, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}, Filling -> Top, 
   FillingStyle -> White];
Show[h1Plot, phiSatPlot, phiPlot, erasePlot, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[0, 0.050, 0.002]}, {Range[0, 50, 10], 
    None}}]
```

Comment: Thanks @cvgmt! I don´t think I can remove h1Plot entirely since it shows enthalpy lines that are important to the chart.

Comment: @JulioAraujoDosSantos  updated.

Comment: thank you very much my friend! It solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option with your boundary function `Y[1,T]`

Note that you don't need to plot each contour separately.  The method used below for `newh1Plot` will save memory.

With definitions as in OP then

```
newh1Plot =
 Plot[
  Table[YB[h, T], {h, 0, 200, 5}]
  , {T, 0, 55}
  , PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0.050}}
  , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y <= Y[1, x]]
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
Show[newh1Plot, phiSatPlot, phiPlot
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[0, 0.050, 0.002]}, {Automatic, None}}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much, it helps a lot! And also thank you for the memory optmization tip.